# Error: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'AxesSubplot'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to make subplots in pandas of certain graphs and i keep getting this error: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'AxesSubplot' any ideas on what fix could be used?

```
colours = ['#F5DEB3', '#528B8B', '#9E9E9E', '#FFA500']

sex_and_wellbeing = results_redditThread_df.groupby(['pay_for_sex'])[['bodyweight']].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x['bodyweight'].value_counts()))

sex_and_wellbeing = sex_and_wellbeing.unstack()
graph_sex_and_wellbeing3 = sex_and_wellbeing.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(20, 13), color=colours, rot=0, fontsize=21)

graph_sex_and_wellbeing3.set_title('Number of People who would Pay for Sex based on Bodyweight', fontsize=24)
graph_sex_and_wellbeing3.set_xlabel('Sex payments', fontsize=21)
graph_sex_and_wellbeing3.set_ylabel('Number of People with Certain Weight', fontsize=21)
graph_sex_and_wellbeing3.legend(
    ['Normal Weight', 'Obese', 'Overweight', 'Underweight'],
   loc='best',
   ncol=1,
   markerscale=1.5,
   fontsize=15)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)
ax[0].plot(graph_sex_and_wellbeing)
ax[1].plot(graph_sex_and_wellbeing3)
```

[Code preview here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwRBe.png)

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image. Otherwise search engines won't find it and the question will be closed pretty soon.

Comment: What does `graph_sex_and_wellbeing` look like when you print it at this point in your code?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters i've added my code

Comment: @eclark It's basically a group of bar graphs when i print it out

Comment: `plt.plot()` expects numeric or otherwise plottable data. You cannot feed it some plotting object like an AxesSubplot. So the question is, what are trying to achive here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to exception traceback, you'r trying to convert `graph_sex_and_wellbeing` to`float`. And `float` in Python can accept either string or number argument. `graph_sex_and_wellbeing` has type`AxesSubplot`. You need to get a string or number from this variable and pass it to a float.